# Remove private key from a X.509 certificate

Tags: openssl

Is there an openSSL command to remove the private key from a X.509 certificate (*.pem file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically private key is separate *.pem file - that's the whole point of public vs private keys, they must be separate.

Sometimes for convenience people concatenate private key and certificate *.pem files into one file, which allows server side programs like apache to parse it to find both. But this is not very common, and if it is, you can use any text editor to look at it and edit it.